# Refresh data in an Activity on OnClick method?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

Want to load currently updated data from sever , Using valley api(json response).

onCreate is loading only data for the first time only.after that no new data is adding to the list.

Loading data, on listview(Contains image,text).

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_downloadimg);
        buttonrefresh = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnrefresh);

        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdoenload);

        listItems = new ArrayList<InfoData>();

        listAdapter = new CustomAdapter(this, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


        Cache cache = VolleySingleton.getInstance().getRequestQueue().getCache();
        Cache.Entry entry = cache.get(URL_FEED);
        if (entry != null) {
            // fetch the data from cache
            try {
                String data = new String(entry.data, "UTF-8");
                try {
                    parseJsonFeed(new JSONObject(data));
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        } else {
            // making fresh volley request and getting json
            JsonObjectRequest jsonReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
                    URL_FEED, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Response: " + response.toString());
                    Log.d("Response: ", response.toString());
                    if (response != null) {
                        parseJsonFeed(response);
                    }
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                }
            });

            // Adding request to volley request queue
            VolleySingleton.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonReq);
        }

        buttonhome.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                refresh();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: yourListView.notifyDataSetChanged(); will solve your problem ;)

Comment: Can u add some code, example or explain how it's works?

Comment: If you add your code i might can help you.

Comment: Here is the main code.

Comment: want to load new data every time when the the button is clicked.

Comment: have you tried adding 'listView.notifyDataSetChanged();' in your onClickListener

Comment: listView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
>>java.lang.RuntimeException: Don't call setOnClickListener for an AdapterView. You probably want setOnItemClickListener instead

Comment: you need to populate new data in listItems in onclick.then you can notify adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();` inside your `buttonhome`'s `OnClickListener`, after `refresh();`